# Mobile and desktop version navigation bar different in a website

Tags: html, css, uinavigationbar

I plan to type two totally different navigation bars on a website. In the desktop version would like to use the 2 columns nav bar (1 column for logo, 1 column for vertical navigation bar). In the mobile version would like using the hamburger menu navigation bar. However, I tried a week more and still not success. Besides, the logo of both versions also different.

Here is the mobile and desktop navigation bar that I would like to create.[Desktop Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7mhF.jpg)  [Mobile Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kUsn.jpg)

What type of the coding can apply in this type of navigation bar?

Below is the last code I typed.

```css
*{
  
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Happy Time Two;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2vw;
    margin:auto;
} 

    
nav{
  display: flex;
  
  width: 100%;
  background: #c6a785;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;


}
nav .logo{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;

}
nav ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li{
  margin: 0 0px;
}
nav ul li a{
  color: #505051;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
nav ul li a.active,
nav ul li a:hover{
  color: #c6a785;
  background: #505051;
}
nav .menu-btn i{
  color: #505051;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]{
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 1920px){
  nav{
    padding: 0 40px 0 50px;
      text-align: center;
      height: 10vw;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 720px) {
  nav .menu-btn i{
    display: block;
  }
  #click:checked ~ .menu-btn i:before{
    content: "\f00d";
  }
    
  nav ul{
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    background: #c6a785;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  #click:checked ~ ul{
    left: 0;
  }
  nav ul li{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 40px 0;
  }
  nav ul li a{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  }
  #click:checked ~ ul li a{
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  nav ul li a.active,
  nav ul li a:hover{
  color: #c6a785;
  background: #505051;
}
  }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
 <body>
 <nav>
      <div class="logo col-lg-12 col-md-11">
      <a href="../index.html"><img src="../image/logo/Duchess Cafe name.png" alt="Duchess Cafe name" style="width: 12vw"></a></div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-1 center">
<input type="checkbox" id="click">
      <label for="click" class="menu-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </label>
        
      <ul>
<li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about page/about page.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="menu page.html">Menu</a></li>
<li><a href="../event page/ event page.html">Event</a></li>
<li><a href="../booking page/ booking page.html">Booking</a></li>
</ul>
        </div>  
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because of the script (CDN) that you are using of kit.fontawesome.com. This chance that is happening is most likely in their code. Try removing or commenting out that script line and re-run the website. This is a handy feature because the text doesn't get too small for users viewing it on their phones. It's a good to have feature and contributes to better website design!